# Android contact sync fails

Tags: active-sync

Not like in other [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96171/sync-is-currently-experiencing-problems-it-will-be-back-shortly), contacts entry is actually displayed in google sync list, but sync still fails with same error:
"Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that "Google Contacts Sync" app is enabled. It will be listed only under system apps, not just under common apps.

(Especially relevant after universal android debloater usage.)